# Make a button "Download all files" from a moodle course

Tags: php, file, moodle

I'm trying to create a button into a moodle course to allow students to donwload all resources than can be Downloadable.

Any hints?

I check de `mdl_course` and have course id.
Then I go to `mdl_resource`, where I find the resource I just add to the course.
Then I go to `mdl_files` and i find the file that I just upload.

But don't know how to make a button that find all files from a course.
Any hints?

The problem is that moodle database is not clear. For example: I have the course id, and searching in mdl_resources i find the resources with that course_id. But in mdl_files doesn't use course id, it uses context_id, corresponding to mdl_context, wicht have an instance_id that doesn't correpond to the course id. I'm blocked.

I'm using Moodle 2.7 over Centos.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight The problem is that moodle database is not clear. For example: I have the course id, and searching in mdl_resources i find the resources with that course_id. But in mdl_files doesn't use course id, it uses context_id, corresponding to mdl_context, wicht have an instance_id that doesn't correpond to the course id. I'm blocked.

Answer (score 2):

In Moodle the files are stored in the file system, in an area defined by the variable $CFG->dataroot, as you may probably know. The 'files' table identifies exactly where each file is stored, what is the original file name, and other properties. It also identifies to which component the file belongs to.

When a file belongs to a course, the component (i.e. the table field) is "course". In order to retrieve exactly to which course a file belongs to, you have to retrieve the content of the "contextid" field and go into the table "context" and use it as key (i.e. the row id). Then, the field "instanceid" is your course ID.

This can be done with a single MySQL query.
For example, if you want to find all files belonging to course with ID=657, you can write:

```
SELECT * FROM moodle.mdl_files 
INNER JOIN moodle.mdl_context
INNER JOIN moodle.mdl_course
ON moodle.mdl_files.contextid = moodle.mdl_context.id
AND moodle.mdl_context.instanceid= moodle.mdl_course.id
WHERE moodle.mdl_course.id=657 AND moodle.mdl_files.component = 'course';
```

assuming that your database is called 'moodle' and that all your tables are prefixed with "mdl_".